# Figaro store passwords rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have install figaro gem.
My application.yml file:

```
user: 'm@am.com'
pwd: = 'password123'
```

Also I have in secrets.yml this:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: d2c6dc60d0c86d32c71aa2ec2ae1fff32f338187ceaa12f0d6a294f368760ead01bc1c57115d48b80ab4042b45ca5aceadea1e888f34b5a14ab548eb07e1ad9c
test:
  secret_key_base: f4c0aad565527a57110ccba77def71e2dd1b65799b94d4d24f9b34a8bc42fd01dbc64349c5555dca46b4d5d2ba85f890c718c1de0d20237704c788e4db928c66

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_token:  ENV["secret_token"]
  secret_key_base:  ENV["secret_key_base"]
  user: ENV["user"]
  pwd:   ENV["pwd"] 
  key:  ENV["key"]
```

And I get user login like this:

```
Rails.application.secrets[:user]
```

Which gives me exactly this value:

> "ENV[\"user\"]"

So what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

seems like I should use

```
ENV["key"]
```

instead of `Rails.application.secrets[:user]`